# Canvas рисовалка

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Я делаю небольшую рисовалку, работает вначале отлично, но потом массив забивается и начинает тупить. Как лучше реализовать очистку массива, чтобы нарисованное изображение не исчезало?

```
var canvas, ctx;

var draw = false,
    pos = [];

function init() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 500;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);



    setInterval(function() {
        update();
        render();
    }, 1000/60);

 }

 function update() {

 }

 function render() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      Drawing();
 }

 document.addEventListener("mousedown", OnMouseDown, false);
 document.addEventListener("mousemove", OnMouseMove, false);
 document.addEventListener("mouseup", OnMouseUp, false);

 function OnMouseDown(e) {
    var m = getMouse(e);

    pos.push({
      x: m.x,
      y: m.y
    });

    draw = true;
 }

 function OnMouseMove(e) {
  var m = getMouse(e);

  if(draw) 
    pos.push({
    x: m.x,
    y: m.y
  });
 }

 function OnMouseUp(e) {
   draw = false;
    pos = [];
 }

function getMouse(e) {
   var mx, my;
   mx = (e.cleintX || e.pageX) - canvas.offsetLeft;
   my = (e.clientY || e.pageY) - canvas.offsetTop;
   return {x: mx,y: my};
}

function Drawing() {
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = 7;

    for(var i = 1; i < pos.length; i++) {
       ctx.moveTo(pos[i-1].x, pos[i-1].y);
       ctx.lineTo(pos[i].x, pos[i].y);
}
    ctx.stroke();

}

init();
```

Comment: А зачем Вы массив координат набиваете?

Comment: @shatal В дальнейшем мне они нужны будут

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? В дальнейшем Вам будут нужны координаты, но Вы спрашиваете, как их удалить? Идите "учите"!

Comment: Подозреваю, координаты нужны для того, чтобы потом показать "реплей". Поэтому вопрос должен быть таким: "Я храню очень, очень большой одномерный массив объектов, каждый из которых содержит два числа. При длине массива более 100500 элементов, браузер начинает тупить. Как мне оптимальнее хранить эти данные?"

Comment: Извиняюсь, был не прав. Проблема автора не в большом массиве, а в неумении пользоваться канвасом. Вернее даже, в неумении толком использовать чужой код.

Comment: @СергейСнегирёв код мой, просто я пока начинаю только, но в основном вы правы

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вы скопировали код отсюда: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-simple

Если вы внимательно посмотрите на функцию `render()`, которую вы переназвали у себя в `Drawing()`, то заметите, что в оригинальном коде все рисуется по одному маленькому короткому законченному пути от точки к точке: `beginPath`, `moveTo`, `lineTo`, `closePath`, `stroke` - повторяются много раз в цикле. А у вас то ли рисуется один монструозный путь (т.к. он не объявляется, мне сложно судить), то ли много маленьких незакрытых, которые все перекрашиваются 60 раз в секунду. Вот `canvas` и тупит.

Я "починил" ваш код, докопировав туда несколько строк из оригинала. Результат доступен по ссылке ниже. Очень надеюсь, что вы всё это делаете для самообразования, а не со злым умыслом.

http://jsfiddle.net/4n4s8ccs/